# Showing Arabic text with MessageBoxW

Tags: winapi, unicode, arabic

I'm learning API programming and used "MessageBoxW" to show Arabic unicode characters but this small program failed to show the Arabic characters correctly and rather of that it shows characters have no sense:

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <tchar.h>

int WINAPI WinMain (HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance,
                    PSTR szCmdLine, int iCmdShow)
{
     MessageBoxW (NULL, _TEXT (L"بسم الله الرحمن الرحيم"), _TEXT (L"HelloMsg"), 0) ;

     return 0 ;
}
```

Comment: did you save the cpp file in UTF-16?

Comment: I tried that but had no effect. The same result is still there!

Comment: First, you should be using `TEXT()` (Win32 macro) instead of `_TEXT()` (C runtime macro). Second, have you tried specifying the `MB_RTLREADING` flag? "*Displays message and caption text using right-to-left reading order on Hebrew and Arabic systems*"

Comment: Ok! I used now 'MB_RTLREADING' flag and text direction changed, and used 'TEXT()' and used UTF16LE once and UTF16BE once, but Arabic characters refuse to be shown correctly.

Comment: It would not surprise me if Arabic text requires an ar-* locale in order for MessageBoxW to deal with it correctly. Arabic simply requires a great deal more processing than just being displayed RTL.

Comment: I have no idea how to do it.

Comment: If you are using Visual Studio save file as UTF-8 with BOM, and remove `_TEXT` noise. `MessageBoxW (NULL, L"بسم الله الرحمن الرحيم"), L"HelloMsg", MB_OK);` should work unless yo are using some old version of Windows.

Comment: I'm using CODE::BLOCKS not Visual Studio, and tried UTF-8 with BOM and the program refused to work at all. Errors like "main.cpp|1|Error E2206 : Illegal character 'ï' (0xef)" appeared. I'm using Windows 11 and think that if I've a PC running WinXP that we will have no problem to show Arabic characters that they have compatibility with real Win 32 system.

Comment: I use Visual studio to display the characters you want normally under win11. Have you tried using `setlocale` for locale settings. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/setlocale-wsetlocale?view=msvc-170

Comment: But I've problem with Visual Studio that it doesn't use Borland C++ compiler.

Comment: Borland c++ is a compilation environment under DOS and does not support displaying Arabic. It is recommended that you use `Visual Studio`.

Comment: What's the specific reason that you need to use the Borland C++ compiler? It is a bit... dated, no?

Comment: I think nobody expected that you are using that old compiler. Probably it could work when you switch langauge for programs not supporting Unicode to arabic (but other programs could have serious problems).

Comment: I'm using Borland C++ 5.5, I think it's not a DOS compiler anymore, I think it's a Windows version of Borland company. The problem of Visual Studio is that it lacks some libraries like "conio.h", so some specific programs can't work under Visual Studio.

Comment: @JunjieZhu-MSFT there are a few later Borland C++ versions that run in Windows, but they're all very outdated (more than 2 decades old). \@AhmedCrow conio.h and graphics.h are **not** standard headers, and neither Borland C++ nor Turbo C++ are standard C++ compilers. Using non-standard features are bad and so is using ancient non-compliant compilers. And you're wrong, VS is an IDE and can use other compilers like clang, and it also contains the conio.h header for backward compatibility, although you're not supposed to use. Learn proper C or C++ instead

Comment: Maybe Borland C++ 5.5 is outdated compiler as you said but it was designed according standards, it uses the standard version of C language, I've no idea if it uses C99 or higher. MSVC compiler works depends on another layer of standards that Microsoft accepted, and Borland company doesn't agree in its measurements with all of what Microsoft agreed in its own measurements. Both compilers are using standard versions of C, but their companies have different policies in their compilers designing.